# Find N consecutive integers on a array, whose sum(of consecutive integers) S is a integer that i have

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

[explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUAwm.jpg)

I have been staring at the problem for a few of minutes.
And i did some research before i ask this quest , but it were in different cases and they didn't included what i really need.
I found this piece of code in SO.

```
static int GetLargestSum(int[] array, int n, int sum)
{
    int largestSum = 0;
    int previousSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                largestSum += array[j];
            }

            previousSum = largestSum;
        }
        else
        {
            int currentSum = previousSum - array[i - 1] + array[i + n - 1];

            if (currentSum > largestSum)
            {
                largestSum = currentSum;
            }
            previousSum = currentSum;
        }
    }

    return largestSum;
}
```

And yes this works but if works for only the largest sum.
I tried to modify it to add the sum var into the code but that didn't actually went that well.
So i would really appreciate if someone helps me, bcs i am stuck in this algorithm.
Thank you!

Comment: This looks like school work, the purpose of which is to get you to think out the problem logically (more important than the syntax).

Comment: Where is **n** declared? You don't use the parameters **consecutive** or **sum**.

Comment: @Christopherous5000 it looks to be a hanker rank question

Comment: Yes u are right sir! I was preparing my code to make the variables name to describe the value that they were assigned to! I forgot to rename N, and the sum is to be added

Comment: Yes u r right its a hacker rank quest

Comment: @JamesRalston - I'll take a whiteboard over these kinds of eval tools any day to evaluate candidates.  This questions being the case and point :)

Comment: @Christopherous5000 well, unless this is being used as a learning tool! I hope people don't use hankerrrank to evaluate candidates other as a sign of some kinda general interest.

Comment: @JamesRalston - agreed

Comment: @JamesRalston I am only 16 years old , i am learning how to program on my own, no lessons in school no nothing, and my purpose on hacker rank is to learn solving different problems, to gain some experience on solving and train my brain , i have no other interests!

Comment: @user7662267 and keep it up! I recognized it was hackerrank and figured as much. Keep it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to solve it would be to iterate over each segment of the array and evaluate its sum. A crude first draft would look something like this

```
public static int ConsecutiveSumArrangements(int[] vals, int count, int sum)
    {

        var number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (vals.Length - count); i++)
        {
            var segSum = vals.Skip(i).Take(count).Sum();
            if (segSum == sum)
            {
                number++;
            }
        }

        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you SOO much sir.It works, now it makes sense ! Thank you again!

Comment: This most likely will fail on their tests because is quite inefficient though.

Comment: that is why I mentioned crude first draft. It highlights somewhat the logic that should be used, especially how to frame the problem (as opposed to the largest sum method provided).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier think in another way than try to correct this code. An idea is using slide window. Pseudo code look like

```
sum = 0
sol = 0

start = 0
end = 0

// sum of the first m elements 
while end < m
    sum = sum + s[end]
    end = end + 1

If sum == d
    sol = sol + 1

while end < n
    sum = sum + s[end]
    sum = sum - s[start]
    end = end + 1
    start = start + 1
    if sum == d
    sol = sol + 1 
    // in the loop we add the next element and subtract the first element
    //so, we keep the length of m elements
```